# How to test in IE with Linux

Tags: linux, internet-explorer-8

Normally I have two computers to work on - my development machine, running Ubuntu, and a testing machine that has Windows. The testing machine is in surgery, and I need to be able to test in IE8. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to run under wine. I've tried the IE NetRenderer add-on for Firefox, but all it does is take a screenshot of the page. I have dynamic code (ajax) that I need to be able to test.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't bother trying to run it under Wine - such a test would be invalid anyway.

Just install Windows in a VM. It's easy.

Comment: I use VirtualBox on Ubuntu, and it works well. There are even tools you can use to test multiple versions of IE in the same VM... Like this: http://www.spoon.net/Browsers/. Buying an extra copy of Windows will sting, but get a retail version so you can re-install in another VM if something gets corrupted or lost.

Comment: You probably know this, but you need to have a valid Windows license for that VM.

Comment: vmware player is nice, although you would need a valid windows license.

Comment: @EmmyS: I don't know about your situation, but one of the companies I worked for had several unused WinXP Home licenses - apparently they were bought with the devs' computers, but the devs installed various Linuxes instead; maybe you could be in a similar situation.

Comment: I may be late to the party, but Microsoft has some official IE VMs at http://modern.ie

Comment: @h4ck3rm1k3 ievms + iectrl https://github.com/xdissent/iectrl is wonderful https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/557066/4644866/4cb83598-5461-11e4-88dd-df8c4eba44df.png

Answer (score 28):

I'm on linux and using VirtualBox and various Windows images sourced from 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

They're supplying old windows versions with updated license which super seeds the default. Meaning you can restore an image back to its 30 day trail indefinitely.

I use the same system at work on OSX

EDIT: The original answer was referencing this page with the images:
http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Comment: Real nice one. Thx for the link

Answer (score 2):

I've used this website very sparingly (when I didn't have a Windows machine with IE Tester). It eventually costs a subscription fee, but you can do a free trial, as well.

http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 0):

This topic is at https://askubuntu.com/questions/190425/how-to-install-internet-explorer-multiple-versions
I am using http://www.playonlinux.com. After install playOnLinux program, run it and add new IE8 or other.